# Angular 5 Routing - Navigate to route by typing URL into address bar returns Handler for Request not found (404)

Tags: angular-routing, angular5

I am using Angular 5 to talk to a Service Stack back end.

I can load my home page by typing in the root address: http://127.0.0.1:8088 and from there I can navigate to all my defined routes using the relevant links.

However if I try to manually type in a route, i.e. http://127.0.0.1:8088/home or http://127.0.0.1:8088/searcharchive I get:

> Handler for Request not found (404):
>
> Request.HttpMethod: GET
>
> Request.PathInfo: /home
>
> Request.QueryString:    Request.RawUrl: /home

My routing codes is as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'searcharchive', component: SearchArchiveComponent },
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}    
];

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],

  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

And the HTML template is:

```
 <nav>
   <a [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a>
   <br/>
   <a [routerLink]="['/searcharchive']">Search Archive</a> 
   <br>
   <div class="container-admin-nav">
     <a [routerLink]="['/admin']">Admin Module</a>
   </div>
 </nav>
```

This is causing a real headache as not only can I not navigate using the address bar I cannot even do simple things like adding images, as no matter where I place the image It can't be displayed. When looking at the developer tools I get GET http://127.0.0.1:8088/logoTransparent.png 404 (Not Found) so I can only surmise that routing is (once again) getting in the way some how.

Comment: Did you set <base href="/"> in the index.html? What url shows the browser when you navigate to http://127.0.0.1:8088?

Comment: I assume there is an Error with your Server-Configuration. If you want to use Angular correctly, every route (except some API-Routes) should return the index.html of your SPA. Check this: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Single-page-apps

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem because I was using

> **proxy configuration.**

**Angular app** was my front-end and I had a **SpringBoot** app as back-end.

In my `proxy.config.json file` I had the following:

```
{
"/**": { <-- **marked line**
  "target": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "protocol": "http:",
    "port": 8080
  },
  "secure": false,
  "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

So, whenever I **typed in** any route in the address bar, it would get rerouted to my SpringBoot app because of the marked line... and I didn't want that. I just wanted my back-end requests from my services to be rerouted to my back-end.

## **Solution:**

I added `/api` to my **back-end requests** (in all my services) and then, in `proxy.config.json` I just removed `/api` from the url. To achieve this, I just added `"pathRewrite": { "^/api": "" },` to my `proxy.config.json` which now looked like this:

```
{
"/api/**": {
  "target": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "protocol": "http:",
    "port": 8080
  },
  "pathRewrite": {
    "^/api": ""
  },
  "secure": false,
  "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```